# Saving Data from CSV to Realm

Tags: java, android, csv, realm

I have been creating a Dictionary App i have all words saved in the **.csv** file
when app is run First Time, this method should save all the words to realm db but saving only few.

> Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@286858df rejected from io.realm.internal.async.RealmThreadPoolExecutor@273caff5[Running, pool size = 13, active threads = 13, queued tasks = 100, completed tasks = 1]

```
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();



    //adding to db satrt
    if (!(realm.isEmpty())) {
        Log.v("DB","already there!!");
    } else {
        Log.v("DB","Not Found!!");
        String csvFile = "longevity.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(csvFile)));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
                final String[] oneWord= line.split(cvsSplitBy);



                realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
                        Word user = bgRealm.createObject(Word.class);
                        user.setWord(oneWord[1]);
                        user.setMeaning(oneWord[2]);
                        user.setSynonyms(oneWord[3]);
                    }
                }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Log.v("TAGGED","SAVED");
                    }
                }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable error) {
                        Log.v("TAGGED","FAILED");
                    }
                });
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

is there A Better way to ship prepopulated Relam dataBase with android,
i have 146800 words to be saved to db when app is run First Time, this method saving only few words then giving error show above!

Comment: You should run the entire thing in one transaction instead of 146800 transactions...

Comment: yes just did that but taking too much time to compile, do you know how can i ship prepopulated db with realm?

Comment: You can create your initial database and distribute it with your app: https://realm.io/docs/java/1.1.1/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.Builder.html#assetFile-android.content.Context-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use 1 transaction instead of 146800 transactions. Also consider using 1 instance to save your Realm object, instead of creating 146800 objects.

```
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
            String csvFile = "longevity.csv";
            BufferedReader br = null;
            String line = "";
            String cvsSplitBy = ",";
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(csvFile)));
                Word user = new Word();
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    // use comma as separator
                    final String[] oneWord = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                    user.setWord(oneWord[1]);
                    user.setMeaning(oneWord[2]);
                    user.setSynonyms(oneWord[3]);
                    bgRealm.insert(user);
                }
            } catch(Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw e;
            } finally {
                if(br != null) {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.v("TAGGED", "SAVED");
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            Log.v("TAGGED", "FAILED");
        }
    });
```

EDIT: You should consider using a [CSV parser library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/), because `String.split()` is memory-intensive.

Instead of

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
```

Consider this

```
final CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader());
for (final CSVRecord record : parser) {
    ...
```

Comment: @phpdroid have you checked the speed of this solution? I used `insert()` because it's faster, and reduced the object creation count.

Comment: However I think `String.split()` might be less performant than using a CSV-parser library: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Comment: thanks well speed doesn't matter now! i will create realm db and ship with the app.

Comment: using https://realm.io/docs/java/1.1.1/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.Builder.html#assetFile-android.content.Context-java.lang.String-