# Reducing size of Realm database shipping with app

Tags: java, android, resize, compression, realm

Am making a Dictionary as my First android Project 
when the app is Run first time am using

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
            .migration(new Word())
            .assetFile(this,"Default.realm")
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .build();

    realm=realm.getInstance(config);
```

this Code to create my Shipped in .realm File as a Default Realm DataBase
But the Size of the Database is Huge after Normalizing as around **20MB**
Is there a better way to Ship **.realm** File so as to reduce it's size.
Already tried shipping as csv but taking too much time to convert to .realm

Comment: Why does your initialization require a migration?

Comment: What do you mean after "normalizing?

Comment: if i don't give migration throws error.

Comment: It sounds like your `assetFile` doesn't have the proper schema and needs to be updated.

Comment: How did you convert the csv file to Realm? And how many records are there? 20 MB sounds like a really big db.

Comment: 150000 records by this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954026/saving-data-from-csv-to-realm

Comment: With 20 MB and 150000 objects, the average size of an object is 140 bytes. What does a record/object contain?

Comment: id, word, meaning, synonyms

Comment: Can the "meaning" be long - like 70 letters (remember that Java is using 2 bytes per letter)?

Comment: What's the size of the CSV?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce 19.5Mb is the size

Comment: ...it's kinda to be expected that the Realm would be similar size then if the raw data is that much, no? unless you compress the meanings manually or something

Comment: I am new to realm I  thought experienced coder must have some other way round..for a thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am facing same issue. I have pre populated sqlite of 2.5 MB in my android asset folder but when I migrated to realm I got same data with 75MB file.

I try to reduce the size and I got a one solution. May be that help you out.

```
Open Realm Browser -> File -> Export -> Compacted Realm.
```

After that I got 3.5MB file.

Comment: am a windows user

Comment: I am really sorry, I am not sure how I can help you on Windows platform.

Comment: for new version of realm studio : File -> Save Data -> Local Realm . 
also realm studio available for mac windows and Linux from here:
https://realm.io/products/realm-studio/#download-studio